# Optimizing Adaptive Streaming with FFMPEG

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg, webm, mpeg-dash

I am working on a video on demand website, I am using laravel 5.7, FFMPEG and DASH player from (dashif.org). Got some questions.

Extracting audio like:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -vn -acodec libvorbis -ab 128k -dash 1 my_audio.webm
```

Converting video like:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -keyint_min 150 \
-g 150 -tile-columns 4 -frame-parallel 1  -f webm -dash 1 \
-an -vf scale=160:190 -b:v 250k -dash 1 video_160x90_250k.webm \
-an -vf scale=320:180 -b:v 500k -dash 1 video_320x180_500k.webm \
-an -vf scale=640:360 -b:v 750k -dash 1 video_640x360_750k.webm \
-an -vf scale=1280:720 -b:v 1500k -dash 1 video_1280x720_1500k.webm
```

Creating manifest like:

```
ffmpeg \
-f webm_dash_manifest -i video_160x90_250k.webm \
-f webm_dash_manifest -i video_320x180_500k.webm \
-f webm_dash_manifest -i video_640x360_750k.webm \
-f webm_dash_manifest -i video_1280x720_1500k.webm \
-f webm_dash_manifest -i my_audio.webm \
-c copy \
-map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -map 4 \
-f webm_dash_manifest \
-adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=0,1,2,3 id=1,streams=4" \
my_video_manifest.mpd
```

Now the problems:

1. Video conversion takes a lot of time on the latest i5 8gb
   think-pad running Ubuntu 18. 4minute mp4 took more than 30minute. 10minute, 720p MP4 took forever, had to kill the process. Is
   that normal? Any idea to optimize?
2. Need to find out original
   video's dimension so that I can avoid dimension conversion more than
   the original. `ffprob` looks fine in command but produces too much of
   information than required, is there any simple function?
3. Converted webm file is bigger in size than original mp4, original
   mp4 of 720p was 33MB, but 640p webm is 76MB. Is that normal or
   something wrong?

Any suggestions to optimize the process are welcome.

Comment: These three problems could each be split into their own questions, but in short: 1) Depends entirely on your encoding parameters (quality, speed option, codec), 2) With [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg)'s FFProbe class: `$ffprobe->streams($file)->videos()->first()->get('height')`, 3) Yes it's common when re-encoding video, and depends again on your parameters and could still indicate you're not using optimal settings. This one could lead you down the rabbit hole and definitely needs a separate question.

Comment: Please don’t ask more than one question per post. It creates partial answers.

Comment: You'll probably want to try processing only chunks of the video in the background, rather than do it all up font. Take a look at this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-can-i-use-ffmpeg-to-split-mpeg-video-into-10-minute-chunks

Comment: @szatmary sure for next time.

Comment: I will answer next time then. Good luck

Comment: @TravisBritz , going to try php-ffmpeg.

Comment: First question is my biggest concern now